# What does big O mean in KNN optimal weights?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nn

Wiki gives this [definition of KNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm)

> In pattern recognition, the k-nearest neighbors algorithm (k-NN) is a
> non-parametric method used for classification and regression. In both
> cases, the input consists of the k closest training examples in the
> feature space. The output depends on whether k-NN is used for
> classification or regression:
>
> - In k-NN classification, the output is a class membership. An object    is classified by a plurality vote of its neighbors, with the object
>   being assigned to the class most common among its k nearest neighbors
>   (k is a positive integer, typically small). If k = 1, then the object
>   is simply assigned to the class of that single nearest neighbor.
> - In k-NN regression, the output is the property value for the object.    This value is the average of the values of k nearest
>   neighbors.
>
> k-NN is a type of instance-based learning, or lazy learning, where the
> function is only approximated locally and all computation is deferred
> until classification.
>
> Both for classification and regression, a useful technique can be to
> assign weights to the contributions of the neighbors, so that the
> nearer neighbors contribute more to the average than the more distant
> ones. For example, a common weighting scheme consists in giving each
> neighbor a weight of 1/d, where d is the distance to the neighbor.

and this [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#The_weighted_nearest_neighbour_classifier) about "The weighted nearest neighbour classifier"

> The k-nearest neighbour classifier can be viewed as assigning the k
> nearest neighbours a weight 1/k and all others 0 weight. This can be
> generalised to weighted nearest neighbour classifiers. That is, where
> the ith nearest neighbour is assigned a weight ${\displaystyle
> > w_{ni}}$, with ${\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{ni}=1}$. An analogous
> result on the strong consistency of weighted nearest neighbour
> classifiers also holds.
>
> Let $C_{n}^{wnn}$ denote the weighted nearest classifier with weights $\{w_{{ni}}\}_{{i=1}}^{n}$.
>
> Subject to regularity conditions on the class distributions the excess risk has the following asymptotic expansion
> ${\mathcal  {R}}_{{\mathcal  {R}}}(C_{{n}}^{{wnn}})-{\mathcal  {R}}_{{{\mathcal  {R}}}}(C^{{Bayes}})=\left(B_{1}s_{n}^{2}+B_{2}t_{n}^{2}\right)\{1+o(1)\},$

and this formula

> With optimal weights the dominant term in the asymptotic expansion of the excess risk is ${\mathcal  {O}}(n^{{-{\frac  4{d+4}}}})$

Does $\mathcal  {O}$ here mean the [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

To further clarify the answer of @Mohith7548 , the O() notation in your KNN description refers to the rate of convergence of the statistical estimator. This is not about computational efficiency of algorithms, but rather, how far are the estimates output by the KNN algorithm expected to be from perfect estimates (i.e. the best possible predictions) for a dataset with sample size n and dimensionality d. As n grows to infinity, the KNN estimator should converge to the optimal predictor (under some basic regularity conditions), and the O() formula describes how fast this convergence happens as n increases. The convergence is slower with high-dimensional data, because statistical estimation of more numbers is harder (see ["curse of dimensionality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)).

See "[convergence in probability](https://bookdown.org/ts_robinson1994/10_fundamental_theorems_for_econometrics/big-op-and-little-op.html)" to learn more about this topic of statistical convergence rates (which are different that computational complexity).